# Make more storage on VirtualBox ofr Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: virtualbox, 14.10, storage

I am trying to increase my storage space on my Ubuntu 14.10 virtual machine on Virtual Box. I did `sudo apt-get clean` to remove cached files but I now have 579 MB left:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       7.3G  6.4G  579M  92% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.7G  4.0K  1.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           335M  816K  334M   1% /run
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
none            1.7G  224K  1.7G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   60K  100M   1% /run/user
```

I noticed a bunch of `none` filesystems but I don't know what that means or if I should delete them. I also tried `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`:

```
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic                          3.16.0-30.40                             amd64        Linux kernel image for version   3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic                  3.16.0-30.40                             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for   version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                  3.16.0.30.31                             amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

But it looks like I don't have any old kernels to delete.

Is there anything else I can do to increase my storage space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Disk Usage Analyzer/boabab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Usage_Analyzer) to find what is taking up the space:
[image]

You can then use `dpkg -S /PATH/TO/FILE/OR/FOLDER` to find what provides it and remove any unneeded packages. Careful some may be important

Note with VirtualBox you can set up shared folders that link to folders on the host machine - if you close the VM, and set up a shared folder, you can then mount it:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf "name_of_shared_folder" "~/name_of_folder_on_guest/"
```

and use it.

Another (probably much simpler) way would be to [resize the the virtual drive](http://www.howtogeek.com/124622/how-to-enlarge-a-virtual-machines-disk-in-virtualbox-or-vmware/?PageSpeed=noscript) - you can do this by closing the VM and running:

```
 VBoxManage modifyhd “/PATH/TO/VIRTUAL_DRIVE.vdi” –resize SIZE_IN_MEGABYTES
```

you may need to run something like `cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"` if you are using Windows as the host machine. You may want to backup the VDI (the virtual hard disk file) beforehand.

Comment: I'm running the virtual machine on a Macbook Air though, so how would I do that?